# How to set background-image in body::before with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have a style on my web page that uses the body::before to set an image. I want to change this image with jQuery after the page loads.  I've tried doing something like this but with no success.

```
$('body::before').css('background-image','image.jpg')
```

Here is my simple html:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="lib/jquery.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <title>x</title>
    <style>
      body::before {
        content: "";
        background-image: url("http://peterkellner.net/wp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/cropped-peterkellnernet-300x60.png");
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 9999;
        display: inline;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="_test.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot access pseudo elements with the DOM API.

Comment: Can they be deleted and re added?

Comment: Unfortunately not, being they are not in the document tree.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do instead of trying to style a pseudo-element (which are not accessible through DOM API and also cannot be styled using inline styles), you can simply create a new class with the `::before` element and its styles. Then you can simply add that class to the `body` element. **Example:**

```
.loadedBody::before {
        content: "";
        background-image: url("http://peterkellner.net/wp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/cropped-peterkellnernet-300x60.png");
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 9999;
        display: inline;
      }
```

then using `$(document).ready()` and `addClass()`, just add the above class directly to `body` element. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').addClass('loadedBody')
})
```

More info here: https://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: Will this cause a memory leak in the browser if I do this over and over again without freshing the page? That is, if I have a button that toggles the class on the body element.

Comment: @PeterKellner No Peter, it won't. Memory leak might occur when this process is done very rapidly, say within a few milliseconds, and that only on small, low-end devices. But it might put in sluggishness in the page, like small stutters and a general feel of slowness on some less powerful devices. 

Bottomline: Go ahead with it and don't worry about a memory leak.

Comment: @PeterKellner Hey Peter! Just a friendly reminder that if my answer worked for you, please accept it as the correct answer. Just trying to get some sweet reputation points! ;) Thanks!